# Docker - how to ensure commit will persist a file?

Tags: docker

I keep doing a `pull, run, <UPLOAD FILE>, commit, tag, push` cycle only to be dismayed that my file is gone when I pull the pushed container. My goal is to include an ipynb file with my image that serves as a README/ tutorial for my users.

Reading other posts, I see that `commit` is/ isn't the way to add a file. What causes `commit` to persist/ disregard a file? Am I supposed to use `docker cp` to add the file before commiting?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you using docker to save your work? If you're trying to build a docker image for downstream consumption, you COULD do a commt/tag/push process, but the DRASTICALLY more repeatable process is to build a Dockerfile to package your image.

Comment: Include notebook w image as a tutorial. Feels pretty ridiculous to run bash to fetch a notebook from the internet, but is that what I am supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to publish your notebook file in a docker image, use a Dockerfile, something like this-

```
FROM jupyter/datascience-notebook
COPY mynotebook.ipynb /home/jovyan/work
```

Then, once you have your notebook the way you want it, just run `docker build`, `docker push`. To try and help you a bit more, the reason you are having your problem is that the jupyter images store the notebooks in a volume. Data in a volume is *not* part of the image, it lives on the filesystem of the host machine. That means that a `commit` isn't going to save anything in the work folder.

Really, an ipynb is a data file, not an application. The right way to do this is probably to just upload the ipynb file to a file store somewhere and tell your users to download it, since they could use one docker image to run many data files. If you really want a prebuilt image using the workflow you described, you could just put the file somewhere else that isn't in a volume so that it gets captured in your commit.

Comment: Thanks Paul. So I spent some time with docker build last night. I put all of my changes in a Dockerfile (install jdk8, copy the file in (i see your explanation now), set environment variables) over several builds. On my local machine... the builds persisted those changes, but after pushing and pulling... no changes were there.

Comment: If you add the files to a location under a VOLUME command after the VOLUME command in a dockerfile, there is no way to persist further changes in that location using docker build/commit. You need to make a dockerfile that does not make a volume in the specified location (including parent images in the FROM command)

Answer (score 0):

For those of you looking for some place to start with `docker build`, below are the lines in the Dockerfile that I triggered with `docker build -t your-image-name:your-new-t`

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM jupyter/datascience-notebook:latest
MAINTAINER name <email>


# ====== PRE SUDO ======
ENV JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB=yes

# If you run pip as sudo it continually prints errors.
# Tidyverse is already installed, and installing gorpyter installs the correct versions of other Python dependencies.
RUN pip install gorpyter
# commenting out our public repo
ENV R_HOME=/opt/conda/lib/R

# https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s09.html
# Looks like /usr/local/man is symlinking all R/W toward /usr/local/share/man instead
COPY python_sdk.ipynb /usr/local/share/man
COPY r_sdk.ipynb /usr/local/share/man
ENV NOTEBOOK_DIR=/usr/local/share/man
WORKDIR /usr/local/share/man


# ====== SUDO ======
USER root

# Spark requires Java 8.
RUN sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk -y
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java

# If you COPY files into the same VOLUME that you mount in docker-compose.yml, then those files will disappear at runtime.
# `user_notebooks/` is the folder that gets mapped as a VOLUME to the user's local folder during runtime.
RUN mkdir /usr/local/share/man/user_notebooks
```